# The Name Bind does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I like to do a conditional bind as the `Bind()` value may be null in which case I like to default it to the appropriate value.

> The name 'Bind' does not exist in the current context

How can this be solved?

```
           <EditItemTemplate>               
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeZone" runat="server" DataSource='<%# TimeZoneInfo.GetZones().Select(s => s.Id) %>'
             SelectedValue='<%# Eval("TimeZone") != null ? Bind("TimeZone") : "" %>'>                
                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""/>
             </asp:DropDownList>                
          </EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and framework are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<%# Eval("TimeZone") != null ? Eval("TimeZone") : "" %>
```

A more elegant solution (assuming C#) is

```
<%# Eval("TimeZone") ?? "" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, what if I want to bind it as it is in the EditTemplate

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The error message you are getting is that `Bind` does not exist, which is accurate. It is `Eval`, which is essentially short for `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "your-field")`.

Comment: I need to do 2 way binding as such need to use Bind

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I feel like two-way binding with a situation in which you could be binding to something not backed by any data store would result in undefined behavior (i.e. what happens if you are bound to the empty string and change the value?). It could be that the best option is to catch the null in your data source and not in a binding expression.